# Robotic vacuum for pet owner

Tags: cleaning

I'm trying to select a robotic vacuum that will cleanup my apartment on daily basis (3 cats is a lot :) ). Which one should I try? I was thinking about iRobot but with no mapping mechanism they seem rather dumb for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a small apartment with wood floors and one cat. The iRobot Roomba 560 works well if we run it daily, but the bin needs to be emptied every couple of days, and the brushes need to be cleaned at least once a week.  With 3 cats, I imagine it may overwhelm the Roomba's capacity.

On the other hand, the new 700 series models have a higher capacity vacuum bin, and we just bought this new bin for the 560.  In theory this can hold more cat hair and the stronger motor sucks more of the hair off the brushes and into the bin.  We'll see over the next few days how much of a difference this makes...

Comment: Thanks! So it works ok when roomba moves around in circles, right? What about battery lifetime - how often do you have to charge?

Comment: We normally set it to run while we're out. It seems to go for about an hour, and then it goes "home" to its charging dock, so we've never had to deal with the battery running out. The movement patterns are pretty random, and it's not shy about vacuuming the same area multiple times, but by the end it seems to get pretty much 100% coverage.

Answer (score 0):

For carpet I love the Dyson DC39, but with the amount of dogs I have, the tubes, filters, and all parts of the vacuum get dirty and are unusable after a year or so. I go through a lot of vacuums, and I think the DC39 is the best vacuum for pet hair. For robotic, I love the iRobot Roomba 770 Vacuum Cleaning Robot for Pets and Allergies ([reviews](http://vacuumforpethairguide.com/irobot-roomba-770-vacuum-cleaning-robot-for-pets-and-allergies-review.html)). It works really well at picking up dog hair after I use a broom.